# What is the max slots for a Mumble server?

Tags: voice-chat, mumble

Our clan is wanting to research the Mumble server voice chat to see if it would be viable for our needs.  We have a box we can use to host a free Mumble server on, but we need to know what the max slots are.  I haven't really seen a direct answer as of yet while doing my own research.

Answer (score 3):

It is my understanding that the only limits are that of the hardware and connection you use to run it on. You choose any max-es you want to allow.

I guess you could say it's unlimited, but your hardware and, more likely, your internet connection determines how many people you can have on at any one time.

Comment: 1. Determine uplink speed. 2. Divide by number of slot. 3. Set as maximum quality.

Answer (score 1):

Mumble appears to have no hard-coded limits built in. The only limits you'd probably run into are available bandwidth and network latency.

http://mumble.sourceforge.net/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mumble_%28software%29

Answer (score 0):

Mumble does not have a slot limit you could not change yourself.

The number of slots of a server is set by the admin of the server by the [`users` setting](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/Murmur.ini#users). It is **not restricted by Mumble itself or the** (FOSS) **license**.

Aside from this setting of Mumble server, the actual usability of slots may depend on:

- [Systems ulimit](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/FAQ#I.27m_running_many_virtual_servers_or_have_many_users_connected.2C_and_the_server_becomes_unstable) *(Which should only start causing problems with > 8000 users - and then you can adjust your systems settings.)* - *(Actually, I’m not even sure this would be a problem; but I expect it to not be just with multiple vservers.)*
- [Bandwidth](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/FAQ#What_sort_of_bandwidth_will_I_need_for_the_server.3F)
- CPU usage - but you will very probably hit a bandwidth limit before hitting a CPU limit

One success story is an eve online guild using Mumble with **> 1000 concurrently connected users** for meetings, raids and whatnot. They have reported Mumble running **perfectly fine even at peak times**.

In the back of my head I remember of some issue with a vserver hoster that was reported, which had bad I/O performance. I am not sure if that was just an admin usability issue though, when managing a lot of user accounts which then lead to delayed messages or audio. An issue of bad I/O vserver hosting then though.